# Play Framework WS.url stuck forever

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I've been banging my head against the wall debugging a production issue which I managed to downsize to the following side-test:

```
def test = Action.async { request =>

    WS.url("https://linklyapp.com/pricing?utm_content=buffer2f4a8&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer")
        .withRequestTimeout(3000)
        .withFollowRedirects(false)
        .get
        .map { response =>
            Logger.debug("Got a response")
            Ok(response.body)
        }
        .recover {
            case e : Throwable =>
                Logger.error("error", e)
                BadRequest("Couldn't open")
        }
}
```

For some reason this never returns.
I don't see the debug print or the error. A timeout is set. I also tried setting the timeout via configuration. No difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue in the async-http-client used in Play.
(https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2767)

I upgraded to async-http-client 1.8.14 and it solved the problem. (The newest version of Play Framework - 2.3.5 - Uses v1.8.8 in which the problem still exists).

**Edit:**

Play Framework 2.3.5 uses async-http-client 1.8.14. Turns out the dependency for 1.8.8 was coming from ReactiveCouchbase.

See more details here in an issue I submitted:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3540

Comment: Awesome.  Up-voted because you answered your own question and now your poor head can stop hurting! :)